# Ctrl-6 doesn't switch to the last buffer (Neovim)

Tags: neovim, neovim-qt

Just noticed that this doesn't work for me. I have to hit `Ctrl-Shift-6` (`Ctrl-^`) to activate the shortcut. Launching up my Vim it worked just fine so it's not something weird going on with my machine. Any idea what could be up with this? (I've disabled all my plugins (except the default plugins) and my `init.vim`)

Neovim 0.4.3

Vim 8.1

Windows 10

Answer (score 5):

justinmk (current neovim leader?) states

> ctrl-6 only works by accident in some terminals. The actual builtin mapping is `<C-^>`.

https://github.com/onivim/oni/issues/2002#issuecomment-377688787

There is also https://github.com/equalsraf/neovim-qt/issues/170

So it just doesn't work for neovim (nvim.exe and nvim-qt.exe) even though  neovim help is the same as vim for the `:h CTRL-6` chapter.

Comment: `Ctrl-6` works in gVim though, that's gotta be included on purpose, it's not a terminal. Wonder why they didn't implement that.

Comment: It also works in plain vim on cmd.exe

Answer (score 2):

I am using Neovim both on Linux, Mac and Windows. For terminal Neovim, it seems that `ctrl + 6` works as expected for me. On Windows, `Ctrl-6` does not work. FYI, the terminal I am using for different platform:

- Windows: [nvim-qt](https://github.com/equalsraf/neovim-qt)
- Linux: [mintty](https://mintty.github.io/) (Connected to remote Linux server via ssh)
- Mac: Either [iterm2](https://iterm2.com/), [Alacritty](https://github.com/alacritty/alacritty), [Kitty](https://sw.kovidgoyal.net/kitty/) works.

For Neovim GUI client, you can add the following mapping to your `ginit.vim`:

```
nnoremap <silent> <C-6> <C-^>
```